# Get sum of founded vlookup result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a list of surfaces with a certain type, and I need the total of each type. I tried with VLOOKUP function but it only gives me the first result. [I tried with this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319636/find-second-vlookup-value), but it's too complex to get it working for me.

[image: This is what my Excel sheet looks like]

in cell H4 I have this function:
`=VLOOKUP(G4;$D$2:$E$11;2;FALSE)`

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How the output coming `38` for type `A`? Can you explain?

Comment: @Harun24HR check column E numbers against A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `SUMIF` formula and not `VLOOKUP` like below.

```
=SUMIF($D$2:$D$11;G4;$E$2:$E$11)
```

Copy down.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know about the SumIf function (y)